# SQL sum of two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these two tables:

I need to join the payment table with the discount table. The expected output seems not possible since the discounts table doesn't have a payment date. I can only get the net_amount

```
payment table:
id    |  net_amount  |  payment_dt  |  person_id
1001  |  2765.36     |  2016-05-28  |  372
1002  |  2474.76     |  2016-05-29  |  372
1003  |  22694.25    |  2016-05-29  |  384
1004  |  1911.92     |  2016-05-29  |  384

discounts table:
id |  person_id  |  gross_amount | sc_discount | other_discount_amount | other_discount_type
1  |  372        |  3566.7       | 713.34      | 88.00                 | MISC 
2  |  372        |  3202.2       | 640.44      | 87.00                 | PAT
3  |  384        |  3566.7       | 713.34      | 285.34                | MISC
4  |  384        |  27953.10     | 5590.62     | 2236.25               | PAT
5  |  384        |  2655.45      | 531.09      | 212.44                | MISC

*1 - payment_dt is 2016-05-28

expected output: (where payment_dt=2016-05-29)
total_gross_amount | total_sc_discount | total_misc_discount | total_pat_discount | total_net_amount
37,377.45          | 7475.49           | 497.78              | 2,323.25           | 27,080.93
```

Comment: If there is no logical link between records of two table then you can not get the ecpected result. If you can gurenntee that each day has only one record in dicount table and that these days are continues.. meaning today discount is the highest ID yesterday is higestid minus 1,,, then we can work something out... but this is very case specific and very dangerouse if for example one day is missing and breaking that sequence.

Comment: Can you explain your schema a bit more : 

Q1 : Why is "id" in payment table repeating?
Q2 : Why there are 4 payment entries, but 5 discount entries, is it supposed to be 1-1 mapping?
Q3 : Is net_amount = gross_amount - sc_discount - other_discount_amount?

Comment: There ***may*** be a relationship between those two tables.  Discount 1 has `3566.70 - 713.34 - 88.00 = 2765.36` which matches the first row in the payment table.  Same works for discount 2, and discount 5.  Discount 3, however, has no matching payment row.  Discount 4 *appears* to be related to the largest payment, but the numbers don't add up.  You appear to be missing either an *entire table (or tables)* to link payments to discounts or, at the very least, some important fields.

Answer (score 0):

As I see in both tables common column is person_id, you can try to join with it. And for more information you can have in mind natural joins, read about it on The Internet ;)

"A NATURAL JOIN is a JOIN operation that creates an implicit join clause for you based on the common columns in the two tables being joined. Common columns are columns that have the same name in both tables. A NATURAL JOIN can be an INNER join, a LEFT OUTER join, or a RIGHT OUTER join. The default is INNER join. "

Comment: The fact that the two tables contain same column doen't mean that you can link them for the disered out put. You as a customer can make many purchases on many days. How will you know if purchase A is linked to discount X or discount Y? Your logic works only if customer can have only one purchase at most.

Comment: Customer may have many purchases, but via data on the tables we see that the only link between them is perosn_id, and we get everything we need, discount amount for every payments, discount type, and payment date. And because questions i only for payment: payment_dt is 2016-05-28

Comment: @fstafai Acording to the OP given data... `person_id` 372 has two records of payments. In `2016-05-28` and in `2016-05-29`. He also has two records of discounts. How do you know which discount is relevant for which order?

Comment: @Elad I have not made the calculations but amounts from discount table should give net amount in payment table. This will be our way to be sure.Or the questions is not sent with full data and columns.

Answer (score 0):

By assuming :
net_amount = gross_amount - sc_discount - other_discount_amount

You do not need to go to payments table for total_net_amount in the expected output

You can write it like this :

```
Select sum(gross_amount)  as total_gross_amount,
sum(sc_discount) as total_sc_discount,
sum(gross_amount - sc_discount - other_discount_amount) as total_net_amount
sum(CASE other_discount_type when 'MISC' THEN other_discount_amount WHEN 'PAT' THEN 0) as total_misc_discount,
sum(CASE other_discount_type when 'MISC' THEN 0 WHEN 'PAT' THEN other_discount_amount) as total_pat_discount    
from discounts
```

And in case the above assumption is not true, As the aggregation is complete, only 1 row will come in output, you can get all columns except total_net_amount as in above query, get sum(net_amount) from payments table, and join them on true as only 1,1 row.